# How can I use CSS pseudo-classes with GWT's UiBinder?

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, pseudo-class

I've been using the in-line styles approach as recommended by [GWT's UiBinder documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World). I'm puzzled, though, about how to use CSS pseudo-classes with UiBinder; for example, suppose I would otherwise (without UiBinder) have this CSS rule:

```
#myLink:hover { background:blue }
```

Can I implement that rule in UiBinder?

Comment: Have you tried? IIRC, it works just as expected. But shouldn't that be `.myLink:hover { background:blue }`, as in it should be a class, not an id.

Comment: Yeah, don't use ID in GWT, always use classes. I've used :hover many time with UiBinder and it works great.

Comment: Hey! What do you know - it works! That will teach me to make assumptions.

Comment: Could you create an answer that just says "Answered my own question" and accept it so this isn't in the "Unanswered" list anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here so that it is removed from the Unanswered questions list.

It turns out that you can use CSS pseudo-classes pretty seamlessly in UiBinder; for example, the following rule works just fine:

```
#myLink:hover { background:blue }
```